# How can i transform array of objects with 2 ellements into 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to create 2 arrays form one array with object that consist of 2 elements.

I've got array form axios call:

```
chartdata: Array [4]
  [{"total":3,"month":9},
   {"total":5,"month":5},
   {"total":9,"month":2},
   {"total":4,"month":1}]
```

How can i get array of totals and array of months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit "fancier" than the other suggestions, but it is not the most efficient solution. If performance is an issue, then you will need to use the map solutions others have posted.

```js
// Your array.
const chartdata = [
  {"total":3,"month":9},
  {"total":5,"month":5},
  {"total":9,"month":2},
  {"total":4,"month":1}
];

// Easy way to get each set of values.
const [totals, months] = chartdata.reduce((current, next) => {
  return [
    current[0].concat(next.total),
    current[1].concat(next.month)
  ];
}, [[], []]);

console.log('Totals:', totals);
console.log('Months:', months);
```

Comment: @DavidWeldon => I appreciate the feedback. I edited my post to reflect your feedback on performance.

Answer (score 1):

use the build-in javascript function map twice

```
totals = chartdata.map(function(item){ return item.total})
months= chartdata.map(function(item){ return item.month})
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate.